# why I don't have suphp in debian testing

Tags: debian

As far as I can see ( https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=suphp ), we have suphp package in some versions of Debian (in oldoldstable, in oldstable and in unstable) but not in stable or in testing. Why? Is it deprecated or what?

Answer (score 2):

The package *suphp* is orphaned (not maintained) and dead upstream, so Debian decided to remove it because security sensitive packages need upstream maintenance.

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1270208

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=738133

If you really need it you will have to compile it manually.